# htaccess not redirecting correctly

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to redirect to a new domain, but it isn't retaining the complete url on the redirect, it only goes to the homepage. Here is the line in my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*\.old-domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.new-domain.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

For example, if I go to www.old-domain.com/contact-us/request-a-demo/, it should go to www.new-domain.com/contact-us/request-a-demo/

Instead, anything I type after the first "/" is redirecting to the homepage for www.new-domain.com

What am I missing, please help

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could try this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^(.+\.)?old-domain\.com
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://www.new-domain.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Comment: Thank you very much